# How does this Android newbie use the Android NDK and C++ code in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I am a Java web developer; I, essentially, write JSP applications. My most comfortable environment is Linux, but I do Ok on Windows. I know very little about Android app development, and I know nothing about C++.

I have recently been tasked with writing an Android app. The Android app, itself, isn't that daunting, but here is where it gets complicated. The company has a couple of pre-existing widgets written in C++ that they want me to include into the Android app. Currently they are stand-alone Windows applications, but I have the source code.

What I need to know is, can I use the Android NDK to utilize the C++ code in my Android app? Can I use this pre-existing C++ code in my Android app and call the functions like I do classes in java? Can I then compile the whole kit and caboodle into a single Android app with all functionalities of my original code, and the pre-existing widgets?

Like I said, I know nothing about C++, so I have no idea where to even get started. I have done some reading on the Android NDK, but since I have no C++ experience, and **very** little Android experience ( just some tutorials on http://developer.google.com/ ), I don't even know which files I should import into the project.

Thanks

Comment: Flagged as off topic as the question is overly broad and unlikely to receive any non-subjective high quality answers.  The best way to get started with something is find a tutorial and follow though, coming back to ask questions and request clarification for any difficulties you may have working through.

Answer (score -1):

You have not mentioned which framework your C++ code uses, it is important. In the general case, it may be anything from bare Win32 API to Qt.

Android NDK gives you just pure C++ (in fact, stripped-down, without e.g. std::string) without the UI libraries/frameworks that are available on Windows. If that C code does something complex without accessing the UI, it is meaningful to port it; if it controls the UI, it is IMHO useless.
***You cannot just port MVC controllers between frameworks, you will have to rewrite everything.***

There is a Qt port to Android, but I do not think it will be suitable for you (you did not mention Qt first of all). Qt is large and complex, and too much to learn at once.

There is Xamarin/Mono for Android, but it is C# as far as I have heard.

You have to find out if the framework used in your project has been ported to Android. If yes, you might use the port, if no, you will have to rewrite the UI.

Even if the framework has been ported, there is a possibility that you will spend less time re-creating the  UI from scratch and using the C++ stuff as a reference model than trying to learn and configure the 3rd-party stuff. (This depends on the amount of code.) Most likely the UI is anyway not suitable for phones.

You do not have to use Windows for Android development, everything works under Linux. (And Linux is more friendly, especially for a Linux guy: under Linux you can grep the logcat output, the Linux terminal is more user-friendly than the Windows command line box (can be resized with the mouse and the font size changes with a keyboard shortcut), and .sh is better than .bat).

Comment: This answer is very subjective "Linux is more friendly" etc which is not even relevant to the question being asked, futher, it doesn't seek to answer the question being asked which is "how" can this be done, rather than "can" it be done.

Comment: @o0rebelious0o "friendly" -- did _you_ use command-line adb logcat both under windows and Linux? Where was it easier to make the window wider and the font smaller? Where was it easier to copy a portion of the log? And where did you find out that the output is gone because it exceeds the pre-set number of lines?